# ImportError: No module named MySQLdb.constants

Tags: robotframework

Environment:
Python
Robotframework
Eclipse
Macbook Pro

Im getting the following error when  trying to run a test:

> ImportError: No module named MySQLdb.constants

I have tried all the following:

```
brew link mysql-connector-c
brew install mysql
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
pip install MySQL-Python
pip install pymysql
```

The execute find, but none of them seem to fix the issue. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you import MySQLdb?

Comment: i dont need to when running it from my windows computer.
but i tried it there in the init file with no luck :(